# Applying absolute position to appendchild images

Tags: javascript, html, css

My current code displays one random item from a large array on a button click, with the new item placed on the top of the list, and with the dimensions of the table vs. the image, it displays in one column. I want the images produced by this button function to be draggable around the page, so I added the CSS to try to make the position absolute. However, this only changes the way the images display, and does not allow them to be moved. How can I get the CSS to apply to the produced elements instead of the container?

```js
function display_random_image3() {
  var theImages = [{
    name: "Snowglobe",
    src: "/img/vocab/snowglobe.png",
    height: "200",
    width: "200"
  }, {
    name: "Pizza",
    src: "/img/vocab/pizza.png",
    height: "200",
    width: "200"
  }];

  var preBuffer = [];
  for (var i = 0, j = theImages.length; i < j; i++) {
    preBuffer[i] = new Image();
    preBuffer[i].src = theImages[i].src;
    preBuffer[i].width = theImages[i].width;
    preBuffer[i].height = theImages[i].height;
  }

  // create random image number
  function getRandomInt(min, max) {
    //  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;

    imn = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
    return preBuffer[imn];
  }

  // 0 is first image,   preBuffer.length - 1) is  last image

  var newImage = getRandomInt(0, preBuffer.length - 1);


  // display the image  
  var targetContainer = document.getElementsByClassName("container3");
  targetContainer[0].appendChild(newImage);
  targetContainer[0].insertBefore(newImage, targetContainer[0].firstChild);
}
```

```css
#draggable {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <button class="button button3" align="center" id="final" onclick="display_random_image3();">Word #3</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="150px">
      <div align="center" class="container3" id="draggable">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: For a start, your HTML is invalid the `draggable` div must be closed. Also try and avoid `table` for layout

Comment: Next .. `position:absolute` has nothing to do with enabling an element to be dragged. I suggest you read: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API/Drag_operations

Comment: I do not need or want a responsive drag and drop system for this. I am aware of that functionality and that's not my question. I want the images produced by this function to have an absolute position and be able to be moved around the screen.

Comment: You say in your question "I want the images produced by this button function to be draggable around the page". So how do you mean moved around the screen? So not by mouse interaction?